# MySQL combining two count statements

Tags: mysql

I have two different MySQL count queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS stored_counter FROM users WHERE ***

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_taken FROM completed WHERE ***
```

I'm looking for if the count value of query 1 matches the count value of query 2. Right now I am running these two queries seperately via PHP and then using PHP to see if the two queries return the same values.

But i'm looking to see if it's possible to do this with 1 SQL query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this form

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM users WHERE 1 =1) stored_counter,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM completed WHERE 1=1)  total_taken
```

You can add every Select statement that only gives back **one** Result (one field(one row one column)) only) as its own column